# Flutter : VoidCallback does't work with OnTap but works with OnPressed

Tags: flutter, dart, void

I have a StatelessWidget class :

```
class PopupMenu extends StatelessWidget {
final VoidCallback editTaskCallback;
const PopupMenu({
    required this.editTaskCallback,
    super.key,
  });
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton(
        itemBuilder:(context) => [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  onTap: null,
                  child: TextButton.icon(
                    onPressed: editTaskCallback,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                    label: const Text('Edit'),
                  ),
                ),
                
             ],
    );
  }
}
```

Just want to know why VoidCallback works fine with `OnPressed` when i press the TextButton but not with `onTap` when i tap the PopupMenuItem.
Here how i call the PopupMenu class :

```
      PopupMenu(
       
        editTaskCallback: () {_editTask(context)},
      ),
```

Here the `_editTask(context)` method :

```
  void _editTask(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: EditTaskBottom(
            oldTask: task,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Edit: The weird thing is when i added the `print` statement to the callback,the `OnTap` is printing the result but no `showModalBottomSheet` appeared.

Comment: Can you add the error you get?

Comment: There is no error, i want to tap PopupMenuItem() instead of pressing TextButton.icon() , i mean instead of pressing the icon i need to tap widget which has more width

Comment: `onTap` works just fine - add some `print` statement in the callback to verify that

Comment: @pskink thanx, yes it did!!! but the weird thing is i'm not getting the same result as OnPressed i want showModalBottomSheet to appear, so there must be something i'm missing.

Comment: @pskink I'm trying to show showModalBottomSheet() when i tap the PopupMenuItem(), but there is no result when i use the OnTap, but with onPressed in TextButton.icon() the same callBack shows the result of showModalBottomSheet()

Comment: I think in the `onTap` you are providing `popupmenu` context instead of `buid()` method  `context`.

Comment: can you include full sample snippet that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 2 actions and every single action have their "Size" PopupMenuItem are inside all the PopupMenuButton width with a random padding/margin in top and bottom, the TextButton default size are 20.

so where is the "problem" :) ?

probably you are clicking/tapping only in TextButton, if you click/tap in the corner of PopupMenuItem you have onTap working. Try to click/tap in **centerRight** corner of PopupMenuItem.

[Size of TextButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U3Hy.png)

[Size of PopupMenuItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP8hN.png)

If press and hold you can see the area, but TextButton are corvering the size of 20 in PopupMenuItem.

let me know if this help

Answer (score 0):

It is not issue about `onTap` and `onPressed`. If you want to `showDialog` or `bottomsheet`. It shows dialog for few milliseconds and popup immediately.

Try this code:

```
                   PopupMenuButton(
                        itemBuilder: (context) => [
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            onTap: () {
                              Future.delayed(
                                  Duration(
                                    seconds: 0,
                                  ),
                                  () {
                                    showModalBottomSheet(
                                      isScrollControlled: true,
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: Container(
                                          padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                                          child: EditTaskBottom(
                                            oldTask: task,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
                            },
                            child: const Text('Edit'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
```